# jquery fade and slide simultaneously

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to both slide/fade a div simultaneously on a hover, then slide/fade it out at the end of the hover, using JQuery. The slide/fade out work properly, but the slide/fade in doesn't. It just slides in without the fade. Any ideas?

```
#myDiv {
    display: none;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px; left: 0px;
}

$('#anotherDiv').hover(function() {
    $('#myDiv').stop(true, true).slideDown(slideDuration).fadeIn({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false });
}, function() {
    $('#myDiv').stop(true, true).slideUp(slideDuration).fadeOut({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false });
});
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The answer is that once either effects activate, it takes the inline css property "display=none" off of the element.  These hide effects require the display property to be set to "none".  So, just rearrange the order of methods and add a css-modifier in the chain between fade and slide.

```
$('#anotherDiv').hover(function() {
    $('#myDiv').stop(true, true).fadeIn({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false }).css('display', 'none').slideDown(slideDuration);    
}, function() {
    $('#myDiv').stop(true, true).fadeOut({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false }).slideUp(slideDuration);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! For the explanation and the code. This worked marvelously and didn't somehow risk toggling the wrong way as some other solutions (which I could generate only on rare occasion in Chrome). Thanks again.

Comment: It's telling me "Uncaught ReferenceError: slideDuration is not defined". This solution might be outdated.

Comment: @ian it's not shown in this snippet, but the code assumes you've set a var for slideDuration before calling this. For example: `var slideDuration = 200;` for a 200ms slide+fade

Comment: The css in between isn't needed if you only want it gone (no need to fade back in)

Comment: What I if I want to add a delay time before sliding up? I tried adding delay(3000) after stop() but it did not work.

Answer (score 54):

idk if this helps or not, but you can skip the slideUp and fadeIn shortcuts and just use animate:

http://jsfiddle.net/bZXjv/

```
$('#anotherDiv').hover(function() {
    $('#myDiv')
        .stop(true, true)
        .animate({
            height:"toggle",
            opacity:"toggle"
        },slideDuration);
});
```

Comment: Change the true to false: `.stop(true, true` -> `.stop(true, false)` to stop the jerky jump back to start position.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use jQuery to slide, and CSS transitions to fade, so they do not interfere with each other. Degrades nicely!

JS:

```
$('#myDiv').addClass("fadingOut");
$('#myDiv').slideUp(600,function(){
    $('#myDiv').removeClass("fadingOut");
});
```

CSS:

```
.fadingOut {
    transition:opacity 0.6s linear;
    opacity:0;
}
```