# Slide down a div and .fadeIn() the content simultaneously and vice versa with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, slidetoggle

I have a outer div containing a inner div.

I want to slide the outer div and while the outer div is sliding down the inner div should fadein.

**I dont't want to fade in the outer div that is sliding down!**

I got it to work with some workarround by giving the inner content a min height and fade that in. But when the inner content has a variable height it gets messy..

Is there a good solution for this problem available?

I created a fiddle to demonstrate my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Brxv/

The Code:
Html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#outer1').slideToggle().find('.inner div').fadeToggle();">Toggle (will work)</a>

<div id="outer1" class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">Hallo1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">Hallo2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">Hallo3</div>
    </div>
</div> 

<br /><br />

<a href="#" onclick="$('#outer2').slideToggle().find('.inner div').fadeToggle();">Toggle (will not work)</a>

<div id="outer2" class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">Hallo1! We have more height than 50px! <br />#<br />#<br />#<br />#<br />#<br />#</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">Hallo2! We have more height than 50px! <br />#<br />#<br />#<br />#<br />#<br />#</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">Hallo3! We have more height than 50px! <br />#<br />#<br />#<br />#<br />#<br />#</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    background-color: red;    
}

.inner {
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520366/jquery-fade-and-slide-simultaneously

Comment: please make a fiddle of it and put its link here. it will be helpfull for answer givers

Comment: What is 'gets messy' means? I just wanna know.

Comment: i posted code to produce my problem and also fiddle to demonstrate. The above posted link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520366/jquery-fade-and-slide-simultaneously is not (!) what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `queue: false` parameter:

```
$('#element').fadeIn({ duration: 1000, queue: false });
$('#child').slideDown(1000);
```

That will allow jQuery to move onto the slide without waiting for the fade to finish.

Comment: See my edit. I believe that should work. I don't see why you need to fade in the children separate to the parent's animation. It will give you the same effect.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Here a fiddle with my example working: http://jsfiddle.net/6Brxv/1/

Comment: I understand now what i did wrong.. I tried to slide down first and then fadeIn. By starting to fade in the elements, the elements are there with the full 'height' and therefore sliding works the way it should.. Thanks for you help!