# jquery slide on user click

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make div disappear after x seconds.With a simple piece of code,this div will slideDown( jQuery slideDown() method) when user clicks button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flip").click(function(){
$("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
});
<div id ="flip">User click</div>
<div id = "panel">Contents</div>
```

I need this #flip to automatically disappear after x seconds.But of course,the #panel will remain.I'm new in jquery and I want to add some nice looks on  my html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery fade and slide simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520366/jquery-fade-and-slide-simultaneously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if you want it to disappear after clicking or what?

you can use `setTimout` to run code after x milliseconds

```
setTimout(function() {
    $("#flip").hide(); // or .remove() if you want to get rid of it completely
}, 5000); //5000 milliseconds
```

you could put this inside of your click event handler to make this happen after clicking.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply do this using your code:

```
$("#panel").slideDown("slow").delay(1000).slideUp('slow');
```

If you want #flip to disappear, you can do this in the current html format:

```
$(this).next().slideDown("slow").end().delay(1500).slideUp('slow');
```

delay will be in milliseconds..

Comment: that would end up hiding the #panel div, not the #flip div.

Comment: @ry4nolson the #panel div is the element we're trying to hide.. is it not?

Comment: "I need this #flip to automatically disappear after x seconds.But of course,the #panel will remain."

Comment: @ry4nolson Whoops, you're absolutely right.. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a callback function as the second parameter of the slideDown function.
The code within this gets called after the animation is done. If you want to wait x seconds you can use `setTimeout()` function:

```
$("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow", function(){
        //setTimeout(function(){
            $('#flip').hide(); 
       // }, 5000);
    });    
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfZM2/2/

Comment: note that instead of $('#flip').hide(), which is equivalent to $('#flip').css('display', 'none') you could also use $('#flip').css('visibility', 'hidden') if you want to leave the space of the text

Answer (score 0):

Got it,just added som piece of code setTimeout as suggested by @rynolson

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function() { $("#flip").fadeOut(15000); }, 5000)
$("#flip").click(function(){
$("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
});
```