# Slide and Fade div simultaneously

Tags: jquery

Hello my fellow coders!

I'm trying to use slide and fade simutaneously in jquery to make a "msg box" slide up and down, but i did not manage to make it wait (with `delay`) so the user can actually see the text in the msg box. I tried to put the `delay` call before `stop` but it doesnt work. Any ideas on how that can be done?

```
$('#msg_callout').stop(true, true)
                 .fadeIn({ duration: 'slow', queue: false })
                 .css('display', 'none').slideDown('slow', function () {

    $('#msg_callout').stop(true, true).delay(7000, function() {
        $(this).slideUp('slow').fadeOut({ duration: 'slow', queue: false });
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520366/jquery-fade-and-slide-simultaneously

Comment: I dont want to use hover to slide the div up, my approach is to automatically slide it up with delay, after 5 seconds, to give the user a time to read the msg.

Comment: Like [***this***](https://jsfiddle.net/r2bvqmyd/1/)? or [***this***](https://jsfiddle.net/r2bvqmyd/2/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of unclear what you're asking, but most of the time, if you want simultaneous animations, just call them in order, rather than chain them.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2bvqmyd/3/), shortened to 3 second delay for sake of simply seeing it work.

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  // clear simple timer for running later code. Clearing this ensures it starts from begining
  if (this.tmr) clearTimeout(this.tmr);
  // stop any previous running animation and reset elements
  $('div, pre').stop(true, true).hide()
  // run first two animations, note one for parent and one for child
  // also note, the parent has set width, this helps with hidden child
  $('div').slideDown('slow')
  $('pre').fadeIn('slow');
  // that simple timer i mentioned, for delaying next animation
  this.tmr = setTimeout(function() {
    // our last 2 animations
    $('pre').fadeOut('slow');
    $('div').slideUp('slow');
  }, 5000);
})
```

---

Making use of `delay()`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2bvqmyd/4/)

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  $('div, pre').stop(true, true).hide();
  // delay works best on one element at a time
  $('div').slideDown('slow').delay(5000).slideUp('slow');
  // so simply call it on each element, but make sure the times remain hwo you want them or it cold begin to look silly
  $('pre').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
})
```

The problem with this solution is that it wont stop the delay and if your method runs multiple times, it will look quirky.

To see what I mean, open up both these Fiddles. On each one, click the button about 5 or 6 times. Or click to let it open completely, then click again. Notice how my first solution functions the same way every time, but the second one will begin fading and sliding up much faster.

From https://api.jquery.com/delay/

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Comment: The explanation in your answer is quite straightforward and I like that, but I wish I could do that with ```delay``` instead, it would be more elegant and less error-prone. If you modify your answer to use ```delay``` instead of setTimeout, I will gladly mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @AndersonMadeira from the API ~`... .delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.` Just FYI, but yeah, `delay` example coming.

Comment: Hmm, I get It. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just css:
http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/jhj4u699/

```
/* The animation code */


@keyframes example {
    0%   { height: 0; opacity: 0; }
    25%  { height: 100px; opacity: 1; }
    50%  { height: 100px; opacity: 1; }
    75%  { height: 100px; opacity: 1; }
    100% { height: 0; opacity: 0; }
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
#myDiv {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```